# Mixing a trait in a class

Tags: scala, traits

From 'Programming In Scala', chapter 12(on traits):

> The Doubling trait has two funny things going on. The first is that it declares
>   a superclass, IntQueue. This declaration means that the trait can only be
>   mixed into a class that also extends IntQueue. Thus, you can mix Doubling
>   into BasicIntQueue, but not into Rational.

But we can have our class extend any class and then mixin the trait using 'with' keyword.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes. It seems book explanation is a bit wrong.Or is it that I understand it wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But we can have our class extend any class and then mixin the trait using 'with' keyword.

No, you can't. If you try it with this trait:

```
class X extends Rational with Doubling
```

you'll get an error because `X` would have two superclasses: `Rational` and `IntQueue` from `Doubling`. That's what the book says.

Answer (score 1):

Quote this line from book:

This declaration means that the trait can only be
mixed into a class that also extends **IntQueue** . Thus, you can mix **Doubling**
into **BasicIntQueue** , but not into **Rational** . You can only mix in a trait with any other class that also inherits from the super-class of the mixing trait.